# CTAD, initializer_list, non explicit constructor, and call to a function

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Basically, what I want is something like multi_types `std::initializer_list`

```cpp
template<typename ...As>
struct Foo {
Foo(As...){}
};

template<typename ...As>
void f(Foo<As...>) {}

int main() {
  f(Foo{5, 3.f}); // 1) compile
  f({}); // 2) compile
  f({5, 3}); // 3) error
  f({5, 3.8}); // 4) error
  return 0;
}
```

I do understand why the first example compiles. However, I do not understand why the second compiles but the others don't. To me, the second should also not compile if third and fourth do not compile. Is there a way to make third and fourth compile?

Comment: Regarding the second case, because the constructor is not `explicit` that means the empty initializer list `{}` can be converted and to `Foo{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I do not understand why the second compiles but the others don't [compile].

Examples 3 and 4 fail to compile because the deduced template arguments are different from what you expect.

When you write a call (`f({5, 3})`) to a function template `template<typename ...As> void f(Foo<As...>)`, the compiler needs to deduce any missing template arguments (`...As`). These missing template arguments are first deduced by comparing the function arguments (`{5, 3}`) with the function parameters (`Foo<As...>`). If a function argument is an initializer list (`{5, 3}`) [1], **template argument deduction is skipped for the function parameter** (`Foo<As...>`):

> [N4659](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/c%2B%2B17/papers/n4659.pdf) [temp.deduct.call] 17.8.2.1(1):
>
> [...] an initializer list argument causes the parameter to be considered a non-deduced context (17.8.2.5).

> [N4659](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/c%2B%2B17/papers/n4659.pdf) [temp.deduct.type] 17.8.2.5(5.6):
>
> [Non-deduced contexts include a] function parameter for which the associated argument is an initializer list (11.6.4) [...]

Because the trailing template parameter pack (`As...`) is not deduced by any function arguments, it is deduced as empty:

> [N4659](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/c%2B%2B17/papers/n4659.pdf) [temp.arg.explicit] 17.8.1(3):
>
> A trailing template parameter pack (17.5.3) not otherwise deduced will be deduced to an empty sequence of template arguments.

For `f({5, 3})`, the compiler deduces that the template arguments are `<>` (empty), thus **the specialization being called is `void f(Foo<>)`**. Important: This specialization is chosen regardless of what's inside the initializer list. This explains the diagnostics given by the compiler:

> Clang:
>   error: no matching function for call to 'f'
>   note: candidate function [with As = <>] not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to 'Foo<>'
>
> GCC:
>   error: could not convert '{5, 3}' from '' to 'Foo<>'
>
> MSVC:
>   error C2664: 'void f<>(Foo<>)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'initializer list' to 'Foo<>'
>   note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

In a function call, function parameters are initialized using *copy-initialization* from the function arguments. The following statements initialize a variable using the same rules that your examples initialize the parameter of `f`:

```
Foo<> x = {};        // Example 2
Foo<> x = {5, 3};    // Example 3
Foo<> x = {5, 3.8};  // Example 4
```

[1] and, in short, if the function parameter is neither `std::initializer_list<T>` nor `T[n]`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make third and fourth compile?

I think there is no way to change `f` or `Foo` to make your fourth example compile.

To make your third example compile, you can add an overload of `f` which takes an array:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

#define EXPLICIT_TEMPLATE_ARGUMENTS 1
//#define EXPLICIT_TEMPLATE_ARGUMENTS 0

#if EXPLICIT_TEMPLATE_ARGUMENTS
template<class T, std::size_t>
struct identity {
    using type = T;
};
#endif

template<class ...As>
struct Foo {
    Foo(As...);
};

template<class ...As>
void f(Foo<As...>);

template<class A, std::size_t N, std::size_t ...Indexes>
void f_helper(A const (&as)[N], std::index_sequence<Indexes...>) {
    static_assert(N == sizeof...(Indexes));
#if EXPLICIT_TEMPLATE_ARGUMENTS
    // Example pack expansions:
    // return f<>(Foo<>{});
    // return f<A>(Foo<A>{as[0]});
    // return f<A, A>(Foo<A, A>{as[0], as[1]});
    return f<typename identity<A, Indexes>::type...>(Foo<typename identity<A, Indexes>::type...>{as[Indexes]...});
#else
    // Example pack expansions:
    // return f(Foo{});
    // return f(Foo{as[0]});
    // return f(Foo{as[0], as[1]});
    return f(Foo{as[Indexes]...});
#endif
}

// Call as: f({x, y, z})
template<class A, std::size_t N>
void f(A const (&as)[N]) {
    return f_helper<A, N>(as, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

int main() {
  f(Foo{5, 3.f}); // 1) compile
  f({}); // 2) compile
  f({5, 3}); // 3) compile (was: error)
  f({5, 3.8}); // 4) error

  return 0;
}
```